# media disconnected with DNS_PROBE

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ip, media

I am getting a `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET` in windows 7. In Ubuntu 14.04, it just says I have no internet.

I tried to use the ipconfig commands found on google,but most of them wouldn't work because:

> No operation can be performed on Wireless Network Connection 2 whiles it has its media disconnected.

What I have done:

1. I have checked via the device manager that my network drivers are up
   to date.
2. System restore.
3. I tried `ping -t 4.2.2.2` but it failed!

What should I do please?

Note that the rooter is fine, since I am connecting to the internet via another computer.

---

EDIT:

Is your wireless card disabled/turned off?

Could be, but I am not sure. In the Device Manager I can see this option: Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter (which is up to date). Moreover, when googling for hours before posting here, I saw another guy reporting this as his card.

*However*, I do have in Other devices an *unknown device*, for which I failed to find any information.

I also did a windows trobleshooting and the problem found is: "Wireless Network Connection" doesn't have a valid IP configuration.

Comment: Is your wireless card disabled/turned off?

Comment: Try `netsh winsock reset all` and `netsh int ip reset reset.log` and restart.

Comment: Are you sure you have connected to your router on this computer? Check your network settings in control panel

Comment: @DavidPostill I am not sure, please check my edit. I had tried he commands you are saying, they did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sacrificing a Google Chrome, the 2nd half of a date with a latin dancer and all night long on googling, I finally solved it by:

1. Powering off once the rooter and then powering it on once.
2. Typed cmd in the search of the start menu and hit ctrl+shift+enter
   (so that I run as admin) and then I entered the usual commands:

   ipconfig /release

   ipconfig /all

   ipconfig /renew

   ipconfig /flushdns

   netsh winsock reset all

and then I saw an Adobe notification for an available update..First time an update touched me so much!

Thanks all.